# How to use postMassage for Cross-domain access when i need to catch two massage in one parent PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I got a problem two days ago, i needed to get height of iframe from another domain and catch it at parent domain to display iframe without scrollbar.

I solved it this way.

PostMessage function at child domain, sending height of div to parent domain.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('LoanToggler').offsetHeight;
   parent.postMessage(offsetHeight ,"*");
};
```

And the function at parent domain catches Message coming from child domain.

```
var myEventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var myEventListener = window[myEventMethod];
var myEventMessage = myEventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
myEventListener(myEventMessage, function (e) {
    if (e.data === parseInt(e.data))
    document.getElementById('sizetracker').style.height = e.data + "px";
}, false);
```

It works dynamicly very well. child's height is always different so function catches it every time and displays at parent domain.

Now about my problem. 
For example i have `parent.php` file at parent domain where i already have one iframe `index.php` from child domain. I need second iframe too from same child domain but `form.php`.

I tried this : 
Write same `postMessage function` in f`orm.php` but parent domain catches only one massage coming from children. i duplicated cater function at parent domain and chainged variables and function names but this didn't help.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, here i find solution at last.

First child php file.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('LoanToggler').offsetHeight;
   parent.postMessage({v1: offsetHeight} ,"*");
};
```

Second child php file.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('childdiv2').offsetHeight;
   parent.postMessage({v2: offsetHeight} ,"*");
};
```

Parent file where are both iframes. The catcher function everything same as above but only changes two lines :

```
if (e.data.v1 === parseInt(e.data.v1)){
    document.getElementById('sizetracker').style.height = e.data.v1 + "px";
}
 if (e.data.v2 === parseInt(e.data.v2)){
    document.getElementById('parentdiv2').style.height = e.data.v2 + "px";
}
```